# Process listing on a jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, process, jailbreak, ps

I have jailbroken an iPhone 6 with ios version 9.3.1 by pangu's solution. After install OpenSSH, I tried to list all processes are running by the `ps` command, and bellow is the result that I got:

```
 PID  TTY        TIME CMD
 1925 ttys000    0:00.04 -sh
 1945 ttys000    0:00.00 ps
 1461 ttys001    0:00.02 login -fp mobile
```

It seems to me that results are incomplete. Moreover, the `top` command is not working.

```
-sh: top: command not found
```

And my question: How to list running process completely?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Please ask this in a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

From `man ps`:

> By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID (euid=EUID) as the current user
>          and associated with the same terminal as the invoker.

use `ps -A` or `ps -e` to select all processes.

As for `top` it seems like it hasn't been installed on your device.